# Response variable with exponential distribution - how to analyse?

Tags: distributions, anova, factor-analysis, exponential-distribution

I would like to analyse the following data:

- Number of observations: 430 trees
- 1 response variable: diameter growth of trees
- 2 categorical factors: tree species (9 levels) and treatment (2 levels)

The response variable seems to have an exponential distribution ([density](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7752237/ana_growth_distri_without_negative.pdf), [density of log-transformed growth](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7752237/ana_growth_distri_log.pdf)).

This [plot](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7752237/ana_growth_boxplot_all_species.pdf) suggests that tree species has a strong influence on dbh growth, and this [plot](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7752237/ana_growth_boxplot_all_trat.pdf) that treatment hasn't. For some species, there seems to be an [interaction](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7752237/ana_growth_boxplot_all_trat_species.pdf) between species and treatment.

I would like to analyze influence of species, treatment and interaction between species ~ treatment. If the response variable was normally distributed, I guess an ANOVA would be adequate. However, due to the exponential distribution, I am unsure about how to proceed further.

I made an ANOVA (`aov(dbh.growth ~ species * treat, data=df)` that showed significant `Pr(>F)` values for both factors + interaction (see [analysis plots](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7752237/anova_ana_trat_species.pdf)), but are the results usable?

What possibilities are there for factor analysis with exponentially distributed data?

Are there any transformations I might use the transform the data to a normal distribution?

Thanks for any help... I'm really stuck here. ;)

Comment: I don't see exponential distributions here.  The plots indicate you have mixtures of distributions, each of which may be symmetric or close to it.  So the first thing to do is a robust ANOVA (such as [median polish](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/software/dataplot/refman1/ch3/median_p.pdf)) and investigate its *residuals*.  This may show that ANOVA is fine.  Otherwise, it will suggest ways to re-express the data that leave symmetrically distributed residuals.

Answer (score 2):

You could try a parametric survival regression with no censoring and an assumed exponential distribution: `survreg(Surv(dbh.growth) ~ species * treat, data=df,dist="exponential")`